# Finding the Missing Word in a Crossword

Tags: logical-deduction, combinatorics, grid-deduction

On each of the 25 cells of this board, place one of the letters A, C, M or S so that, in alphabetical order, nine of the ten words that can be read down or across are the following:

AACAC

AMCAS

AMMAA

CSCSA

MCMMM

MMMCC

SAMAC

SAMCA

SAMCS

What is the tenth word?

[image]

Puzzled based on a similar one by the late Professor Joe Kanhauser of Macalester College included in Stan Wagon's blog: http://stanwagon.com/pow/index.php

Answer (score 5):

The grid looks like this:

> [image]

Making the missing word

> '**CAMAS**' (fourth column)

And listing the words:

> AACAC - fourth row
> AMCAS - second column
> AMMAA - second row
> CSCSA - fifth row
> MCMMM - third row
> MMMCC - third column
> SAMAC - first column
> SAMCA - fifth column
> SAMCS - first row

Explanation of how I got the grid.

> Firstly, notice that all of the words' middle letters are either 'M' or 'C'. This means that the third row and third column must be words with only Ms or Cs.
>
> The only two possibilities therefore are MCMMM and MMMCC. There's two ways they can go into the grid, and I tried them like so first.
>
> Next, top left must be a letter where there are two different words with the third letter 'M'. The only possible letter is 'S'. All words beginning with 'S' have an 'A' afterwards, so the first three letters of the first row and column must be 'SAM':
>
>  [image]
>
> There are only two words beginning with 'A' that have the same second letter, so the square at (2,2) must be an 'M'. This makes the second row 'AMMAA' and the second column 'AMCAS'.
>
> From there, the only word with an 'S' in second place is 'CSCSA', so that must be the fifth row. This makes the first column 'SAMAC'. The fourth row must also be 'AACAC'. Finally the rest can be filled out and we get the missing word.

I know this logic is flawed as the missing word could fill in, but that was my thought process that got me the answer so I guess it works here :)